# Disable/Hide Items in a CListCtrl MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I want to hide or disable Items with SetItemState(). The CListCtrl is in Report View.
It must be something like this  `m_List.SetItemState(1, DISABLE, DISABLE);`

I searched but didnt find the right nState

If there is another solution than SetItemState, it also will be ok

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

There is no item state to represent a disabled (grayed) item. See [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774733%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
The only way to solve this is your own implementation and using custom draw. That is the way I do it.

You can easily prevent the user to select an item when you trap [LVN_ITEMCHANGING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Just filter the state Change to LVIS_SELECTED and return TRUE to prevent the change.

Answer (score 0):

You can give visual feedback. I would derive a class `CMFCListCtrl` and override `OnGetCellBkColor` and `OnGetCellTextColor` methods to achieve it.

And I would override the its response to selection to unselect when selecting an unselectable item. However for this part, I am not so sure if it is doable.